# Openerp QR code generation using client side validation

Tags: jquery, odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I would like to generate a QR code based on the field roll number and display it in a div container with id named "vyas_qrcode" using a javascript file(client side validation).

1. The Logic for QR code generation is inside the js file(qrcode_js.js) in start: function () inside, this.$el.append(). The code inside the append works when typing inside chromes console but shows error here in this file saying '<' un-expected.
2. I tried putting this logic directly inside the xml but it loads even before the page and dom is loaded and so the qrcode is generated but with empty values.
3. I know that I am supposed to put it inside the "start: function() " which refers to the page and DOM being loaded but am not sure about how to go from there.
4. I would also like to know how to validate field "name" and make it such that it has between 5 and 10 characters and also it should not contain symbols. And I don't want to do this from the python file but from the client side, either in the "init: function()" or the "start: function()" .
5. And Thanks to everybody for taking your valuable time to help me out.

The 3 files I have created are,

```
from osv import osv,fields

    class qrcode_clientside(osv.osv):

        _name = 'qrcode.clientside' # Name of the table.

        _columns = {

        'name': fields.char("Name", size=64, requried=True),    # Name of the person. The name should be between 5 and 10 characters and must not contain symbols . How to do this with the javascript file(qrcode_js.js)
        'roll_number': fields.integer("Roll Number", required=True),    # Roll number of the person.
        }
```

Then the xml file qrcode_js.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_qrcode_clientside">
            <field name="name">QRCode Generation</field>
            <field name="res_model">qrcode.clientside</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem name="QR Code JS" id="qrcode_js_menu" sequence="10" />
        <menuitem name="QR Code Side Menu" id="qrcode_js_sidemenu" parent="qrcode_js_menu" sequence="3" />
        <menuitem name="QR Code Generator" id="qrcode_js_finalmenu" parent="qrcode_js_sidemenu" sequence="4" action="action_qrcode_clientside" />

        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_qrcode_clientside_form" >
            <field name="name">qrcode.clientside Form View</field>
            <field name="model">qrcode.clientside</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="QRCode Clientside Generation" version="7.0">
                    <sheet>
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="name" /> <!-- The name should be between 5 and 10 characters and must not contain symbols . How to do this with the javascript file(qrcode_js.js).-->
                                <field name="roll_number" class="roll_number_class" />
                             </group>
                             <group>
                                <div id="vyas_qrcode" width="100" height="75" >    <!-- This is where the QR Code should be generated. It should have the value of the Roll number of the person. -->
                                        QR Code Placeholder
                                </div>
                            </group>
                    </group>
                     </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>


        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_qrcode_clientside_tree" >
            <field name="name">qrcode.clientside Tree View</field>
            <field name="model">qrcode.clientside</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="name" />
                <field name="roll_number" />
            </field>
        </record>


    </data>
</openerp>
```

Then the Javascript file qrcode_js.js .

```
openerp.js_qrcode_vyas = function(instance){

instance.js_qrcode_vyas = {};

alert("Inside the main function ");

instance.js_qrcode_vyas.qrcode_clientside = instance.web.Widget.extend({

init: function(parent, name){
    console.log("qrcode_clientside page has been loaded.");
},

start: function(){
    this.$el.append('
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js_qrcode_vyas/static/src/js/jquery.qrcode.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                        rollnumber_from_field = $(".roll_no_class").text();     // Getting the value of Roll Number from the roll_number field.
                        qroptions = { width: 40,height: 40, text:rollnumber_from_field  , size: 100, render:"image" }; // To pass arguments to get the QR code.
                        setTimeout(function(){$("#vyas_qrcode").qrcode(qroptions);}, 4000); // Generating the QR code and displaying it after a delay of 4 seconds.
                        });

        </script>
        ');

},
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to append javascript tags, you should be able to do something like:

```
start: function(){
                    rollnumber_from_field = this.val();     // Getting the value of Roll Number from the roll_number field.
                    qroptions = { width: 40,height: 40, text:rollnumber_from_field  , size: 100, render:"image" }; // To pass arguments to get the QR code.
                    setTimeout(function(){$("#vyas_qrcode").qrcode(qroptions);}, 4000); // Generating the QR code and displaying it after a delay of 4 seconds.
                    });
                    ...
```

(I haven't tested it). Have a look at some of the other widgets. Or look at the tutorial: http://odoo-80.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howtos/web.html#widgets-basics

Also, make sure your vyas_qrcode.js file is included in your `__openerp__.py` file.